# Renaming namespaces in MonoTouch

Tags: ios, xamarin.ios, monodevelop, xamarin, xamarin-studio

After I renamed my namespaces in my MonoTouch-Solution in MonoDevelop I can't build the app, because all the referencing outlets of the UI-components are not found.

I already reopened my XIB in Interface Builder, changed something and saved it, but the code still won't run.

I guess, the IB elements don't care about namespaces defined in MonoTouch. Is there a way to get around this issue?

Comment: Did you open up all your partial classes (*.designer.cs files) and update the namespaces in there as well?

Comment: Yes, I did this yesterday and again today. The difference: It worked today :-(. Thanks. Pls post an answer so that I can mark it as the correct one!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Double check the namespaces on all your partial classes (*.designer.cs files).

C# would not be able to use any outlets from the original class, if the namespace was not the same.

Answer (score 1):

You have to change name spaces both in .CS controllers and also in designer.cs files.

In addition go to project -> properties and in application tab write same namespace in default and assebmly name save to avoid namespace error when you create new classes